# Integrate Datepicker with Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am trying to integrate a datepicker on a editText in my app that works with Firebase. Until now that information was entered by text and it worked correctly, but when integrating the datepicker and opening the form in which the datepicker is located the application crashes showing an error:

> "Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo".

Even if I open a new form that does not contain any dates yet, it also crashes, however I have tried to create a new project only with the datepicker and it works correctly. I think the problem has to do with the way it is integrated with Firebase. Can anybody help me?

Below I show the code, the edittext on which is include the datePicker is Date_Ult_Taller

DatepickerFragment.kt:

```
class DatePickerFragment (val listener: (day:Int, month:Int, year:Int) -> Unit ): DialogFragment(),
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


    override fun onDateSet(p0: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        listener(dayOfMonth, month, year)
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        return DatePickerDialog(activity as Context, this, year, month, day)
        }
    }
```

ActivityForm:

```
abstract class ActivityForm : AppCompatActivity() {

    var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    var idCoche: String? = null

    val claveFechaUltTaller = "fechaUltTaller"
   
        val txtFechaUltTaller = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Date_Ult_Taller)
        
        idCoche = intent.getStringExtra("idCoche")
        if (idCoche != null)
          db.collection(coleccionCoches).document(idCoche!!).get().addOnSuccessListener {
                
                val nombreCoche = it.data?.get("nombre") as String    
                val fechaultTaller = it.data?.get(claveFechaUltTaller) as? String   
                txtFechaUltTaller.setText("${fechaultTaller ?: ""}")
                
            }
        }
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener {
            val fechaUltTaller = txtFechaUltTaller.text.toString()
            val coche: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
            if (idCoche == null) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.email?.let { email ->
        
        Date_Ult_Taller.setOnClickListener { showDatePickerDialog() }
    }
    private fun showDatePickerDialog() {
        val datePicker = DatePickerFragment { day, month, year -> onDateSelected(day, month, year) }
        datePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "datePicker")
    }
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun onDateSelected(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int) {
        with(Date_Ult_Taller) { Date_Ult_Taller.setText("$day-$month-$year") }
    }
```

This is the first question that I do here, sorry if there is any problem and please comment it to me in that case. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **300 (three hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Ok, I remove a lot of innecesary code, thank you.